# How can I get a popup and type in image link in there and make my image appear on the box below?

Tags: react-native

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, StatusBar, Dimensions, TextInput, Platform, ScrollView,TouchableOpacity, Button } from 'react-native';
import { AppLoading } from "expo";
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
const { height, width } = Dimensions.get("window");
import Display from "./display";
import Modal from "react-native-modal";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {

  return(
    <View style={styles0.container}>
      <StatusBar barStyle= "light-content" />
      <Text style={styles0.title}>Junior Facebook</Text>
      <View style={styles0.mainwhite}>
        <View style={styles0.first}>
          <TextInput 
          style={styles0.input1}
          placeholder = "Enter your email" 
          />
          <TextInput 
          style={styles0.input1}
          placeholder = "Enter your password"
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles0.second}>
          <TouchableOpacity 
          style={styles0.button}
          onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("Newsfeed")}
          >
            <Text>SignUp</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text>Log In</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}


function Member({navigation}) {
  return (
     <View style={{alignItems: "center", backgroundColor: "lightgreen", flex: 1}}>
      <Text>Junior Facebook</Text>
        <TextInput placeholder="Email" style={{width: 200, height: 60, borderStyle: "solid", borderWidth: 2}}/>
        <TextInput placeholder="Password" style={{width: 200, height: 60, borderStyle: "solid", borderWidth: 2}}/>
        <TextInput placeholder="Confirm Password" style={{width: 200, height: 60, borderStyle: "solid", borderWidth: 2}}/>
        <TextInput placeholder="Name" style={{width: 200, height: 60, borderStyle: "solid", borderWidth: 2}}/>
        <TextInput placeholder="Gender" style={{width: 200, height: 60, borderStyle: "solid", borderWidth: 2}}/>
        <TextInput placeholder="Location" style={{width: 200, height: 60, borderStyle: "solid", borderWidth: 2}}/>
        <TextInput placeholder="Alma Mater" style={{width: 200, height: 60, borderStyle: "solid", borderWidth: 2}}/>
        <Button style={{width: 100, height: 30}}title="Meeting"
        onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("Meeting")}
        >Meeting</Button>
    </View>
  );
}




export default class App extends React.Component{
    render(){
        return (
          <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
              <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
              <Stack.Screen name="Member" component={Member} />
              <Stack.Screen name="Newsfeed" component={Newsfeed} />
            </Stack.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
        )
    }
}


const styles0 = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor : "#FFD6ED",
    alignItems : "center"
  },
  title: {
    color: "white",
    marginTop : 100,
    fontSize : 30,
    fontWeight: "bold"
  },
  mainwhite:{
    backgroundColor : "white",
    width : width -65,
    marginTop : 50,
    borderRadius: 20
  },
  input1:{
    borderStyle: "solid",
    borderWidth: 2,
    width: 300,
    height: 50,
    padding: 10,
    marginVertical: 25,
  },
  input2:{},
  first:{
    marginVertical: 40,
    alignItems : "center"
  },
  second: {
    alignItems : "center",
    marginVertical: 20,
  },
  button : {
    marginBottom : 30
  }
})



class Newsfeed extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(

      <View style={styles1.container}>
        <StatusBar barStyle= "light-content" />
        <View style={styles1.title}>
          <Text style={styles1.title}>Junior Facebook</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles1.first}>
          <TouchableOpacity style={styles1.profile}>
            <Text>프로필</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <View style={styles1.allinput}>
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <TextInput 
              style={styles1.input}
              placeholder = "글 입력"
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <View style={styles1.button}>
              <TouchableOpacity >
              <Text style={styles1.picturebutton}>사진</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity>
              <Text style={styles1.pushbutton}>입력</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles1.second}>
          <ScrollView>
            <Display/>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
const styles1 = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex:1,
    backgroundColor : "#FFD6ED",
    alignItems:"center",
  },
  title: {
    color: "white",
    marginTop : 5,
    fontSize : 18,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    marginBottom : 5,
    alignItems:"center",
  },
  first :{
    flex:1,
    flexDirection : "row",
    borderBottomWidth : StyleSheet.hairlineWidth,
    marginLeft: 40
  },
  second:{
    flex:3,
  },
  profile:{
    backgroundColor : "white",
    borderStyle: "solid",
    borderWidth: 2,
    width: 90,
    height : 110,
    marginTop : 3
  },
  allinput: {
    flexDirection : "column",
    alignItems:'flex-end',
    borderBottomColor: "black",
    padding : 3,
  },
  input:{
    borderStyle: "solid",
    borderWidth: 2,
    width: 200,
    height: 110,
    padding: 10,
    marginLeft : 5,
    backgroundColor : "white",
  },
  button:{
    flexDirection : "row"
  },
  picturebutton:{
    fontSize: 24,
    width: 60,
    height:40,
    borderStyle: "solid",
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor : "white",
    marginVertical : 10,
    marginHorizontal : 0
  },
  pushbutton:{
    fontSize: 24,
    width: 60,
    height:40,
    borderStyle: "solid",
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginLeft : 5,
    backgroundColor : "white",
    marginVertical : 10
  }
})
```

and my Display component is as follows

```
import React from "react";
import {View, Text, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet, ScrollView, TouchableOpacity} from "react-native";


export default class Display extends React.Component{
    render(){
        const {text} = this.props;
        return (
            <View style={styles.pushtext}>
                <Text>일단 한개</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    pushtext: {
        backgroundColor : "white",
        width: 300,
        height: 50,
        marginTop: 30
    }
})
```

When I click the "Enter" TouchableOpacity, a popup should appear. And I should be able to type in an image link in the popup. And when I type in image link in there and click the "enter" text, an image from that link should appear below. How can I do so?

Please help me out here

Thank you so much!

Comment: i recommend you use this https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal

Comment: do you want to add this feature to the ```Newsfeed```?

Comment: Yes. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirements, I made below sample

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Button, Modal, TextInput, Image, } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    modalVisible: false,
    link: '',
  };

  setModalVisible = () => {
    this.setState({ modalVisible: !this.state.modalVisible });
  };

  onChangeText = text => {
    this.setState({
      link: text,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title='Enter' onPress={this.setModalVisible} />

        {
          this.state.modalVisible &&
          <Modal
            visible={this.state.modalVisible}
            transparent={true}
            animationType="slide"
            onRequestClose={this.setModalVisible}>
            <View style={styles.modelStyle}>
              <View style={styles.modelWrapperStyle}>
                <TextInput
                  style={styles.inputStyle}
                  onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
                  value={this.state.link}
                />
                <Button title='Enter' onPress={this.setModalVisible} />
              </View>
            </View>
          </Modal>
        }

        {
          !this.state.modalVisible && !!this.state.link &&
          <Image
            source={{ uri: this.state.link }}
            style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }}
          />
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  modelStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
  },
  modelWrapperStyle: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-around',
    backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
    padding: 10,
    width: '90%',
  },
  inputStyle: {
    height: 40,
    width: '80%',
    borderColor: 'gray',
    borderWidth: 1,
  }
});
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.

Comment: it throws an error - "undefined is not an object(evaluating popupUi.default.show)

Comment: I want the original code and I want to work on popup on top of that. can you elaborate with code please?

Comment: @SeanLee your code bit of unclear for me. that's why I create above sample. Share your whole component with styles or create an expo example.

Comment: I updated my entire code. Please take a look for me. Thank you much

Comment: PLease help me out